# Need explanation on a method-call

Tags: java, interface, method-call, anonymous-inner-class

In the code below:

```
public File[] findFiles (String path)
{
    FilenameFilter textFilter = new FilenameFilter()
    {
        @override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
        {
            if(name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt"))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    };

    File[] txtFiles = new File(path).listFiles(textFilter);

    return txtFiles;
}
```

I understand that an anonymous class, which implements the interface `FilenameFilter`, is defined and instantiated. But I don't understand how the method `accept` is called without being called directly.

Comment: the listFiles() method actually invokes this accept() method with a file or directory name as parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the source code of `listFiles`, the `accept` method is being called. [here's the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/File.java#File.listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29)

```
public File[] listFiles(FilenameFilter filter) {
String ss[] = list();
if (ss == null) return null;
ArrayList v = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0 ; i < ss.length ; i++) {
    if ((filter == null) || filter.accept(this, ss[i])) {
                                   ^^^^^^
    v.add(new File(ss[i], this));
    }
}
return (File[])(v.toArray(new File[v.size()]));
}
```

Comment: Additionally, in your IDE you can attach source code for Java supplied classes and it will help to find out more..

Answer (score 2):

The `accept()` method is called within the `File.listFiles()` method for every File found in the (directory) File it's called on.

This is a [*callback*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) pattern in action.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of `FilenameFilter` requires the accept method to be overridden as you have done so. So when you use `listFiles( FilenameFilter filter )`, the filter in the `listFiles()` method calls the accept method whether to accept or not.

This link will help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FileFilter)